# Google Spreadsheet store some values in other cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get started with scripting in Google Spreadsheets.

How do I store values in cells? I try to use setValues but I don't have permission. I wanted to have a protected range of cells track all the names entered in cells that have this function. The below script only stores one name as a test, but it doesn't work.

```
function storeNames(name) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var storeRange = sheet.getRange(6,2);
  storeRange.setValues([[name]]);
  return "Hello " + name;
}
```

So in cell A1, I set the function =storeNames(B1)

I enter a name in B1, and A1 gives an error as it can't store the name entered in another cell - how do I keep a list of the names entered? Anyone got any tips on how to debug this - all the usual javascript tools don't work, and the script editor log won't work for scripts executed in the spreadsheet, so I'm flying blind.

Comment: You are using so-called custom functions, which are potent but have some restrictions such as: `Custom functions return values, but they cannot set values outside the cells they are in.`. To learn a little more about them, visit the following section of the documentation: [Custom Functions in Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions)

Comment: Thanks, I read the "documentation" such as it is. What I don't get, is why they provide a method you can't use. Surely there's a way to set values in the spreadsheet, given that there's a function to do so.

Comment: Indeed, the method is used in other contexts, but specifically it is not possible to use in custom functions.

Comment: So, is there another way to achieve the result? I don't care if it's custom functions or some other magic

Comment: You can do it from a custom menu or from onEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example, is something like:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range, sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'Sheet1' && range.getColumn() === 2)
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).setValue(e.value);
}
```